# Creating a new loopback project fails

Tags: node.js, angular, strongloop, loopback

I'm trying to create a new loopback project in my windows machine. When I put `slc loopback`, and write the name of the app, and then it is still blocked. I can't choose what version of Loopback to create the project.

Capture :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXeuC.png)

Comment: is the computer stuck or the command prompt stuck ??

Comment: no, i tried in another machine and i have the same problem (windows 10)

Comment: try updating loopback cli